# Search through columns in a datagridview using textbox (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview, find, bind

How do I search through columns in a datagridview using a textbox? I'm using vb.net 2010. I have a Datagridview with a data source. Below is my code for populating my datagridview. The gridview will have 4 columns.

```
Private Sub LoadProducts()
    Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HRMS.My.MySettings.ResortDBConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)
        Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_NET_GetProducts_CompanyID", con)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", CInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CompanyID")))

        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Products"

        dgvProducts.DataSource = ds.Tables("Products")
        dgvProducts.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        dgvProducts.AllowUserToResizeColumns = True
        dgvProducts.Refresh()
    End Using
End Sub
```

*Requirements*: In my form I will have a `textbox` and `button`. The textbox will supply the search string. I need a way to highlight the row when a string is found.

I don't want to open another connection just to search for a string on a dataset. Is it possible to search for string values directly in the datagridview?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a sample code doing what you want:

```
Dim toSearch As String = "this"
Dim colNum As Integer = 0
Dim res = ds.Tables("Products").AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Item(colNum).ToString() = toSearch).ToArray
For Each item In res
    Dim curRow As Integer = ds.Tables("Products").Rows.IndexOf(item)
    dgvSuppliers.Rows(curRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
Next
```

The code above looks for the string `"this"` in the first column of `Table "Products"` and change the `BackColor` of the matched rows to Yellow.

NOTE: this answer intends to reply the OP's question in the way usually "searching a term in a datasource" is understood, that is, by relying on a query. Also, people tend to prefer solutions involving a lower number of lines. These two reasons explain why I relied on this approach (this together with the OP's muteness). The OP has decided to answer himself what he has considered better. I personally prefer iterative solutions like the one he posted (although I consider that this approach is evident to anyone using a `DataGridView`). In any case, nothing can be said a priori about which option is more efficient without knowing the exact conditions (size). The whole point of this note is highlighting that I don't recommend relying on LINQ-based approaches on a regular basis, just wrote what the OP was apparently looking for (unfortunately, I am pretty bad at interpreting the expectations of a persons not explaining clearly what is looking for and avoiding any kind of communication).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) for your requirement.So your code will looks like below,

- Declare (Public)

  ```
  Dim ds As New DataSet
  Dim bndSourceGrid As New BindingSource()
  ```
- Fill *dgvProducts* with a *BindingSource*

  ```
  Private Sub LoadProducts()
  Dim CS As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("HRMS.My.MySettings.ResortDBConnectionString").ConnectionString

  Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(CS)
  Dim da As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("sp_NET_GetProducts_CompanyID", con)
  da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
  da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyID", CInt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CompanyID")))


  da.Fill(ds)
  ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Products"

  '/*--------------------------------------------
  bndSourceGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables("Products")
  dgvProducts.DataSource = bndSourceGrid
  '/*--------------------------------------------

  dgvProducts.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
  dgvProducts.AllowUserToResizeColumns = True
  dgvProducts.Refresh()
  End Using

  End Sub
  ```
- goto *txtboxSerach* and on it's *TextChanged* event

  ```
    Private Sub txtboxSeracht_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    System.EventArgs) Handles txtSearchCust.TextChanged
        '/*here "Name" is the column that you want filter/search
      bndSourceGrid.Filter = String.Format("{0} LIKE '{1}%'", "Name",   
      txtboxSerach.Text)
        '/* sorting method ascending/descending
      bndSourceGrid.Sort = "Name ASC"
    End Sub
  ```
- goto *txtboxSerach* and on it's *Validated* event

  ```
     Private Sub txtboxSerach_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As   
                          System.EventArgs) Handles txtboxSerach.Validated
         If txtboxSerach.Text = String.Empty Then
            bndSourceGrid.RemoveFilter()
         Else
            bndSourceGrid.Filter = String.Format("{0} = '{1}'", "Name", 
            txtboxSerach.Text)
           bndSourceGrid.Sort = "Name ASC"
         End If
     End Sub
  ```

---

- Result

   my *DataGridView* looks like below

  ```
   ID Name    Other
   ---------------
   0  Abcd    321
   1  Abdc    546
   2  Bcdsf   1005
  ```

  When I start typing letter `A` in *txtBoxSerach*

  ```
   ID Name    Other
   ---------------
   0  Abcd    321
   1  Abdc    546
  ```

Comment: Is it possible to add here a `WHERE` statement?

Comment: @ChadPatrick https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.filter(v=vs.110).aspx