# Search Datagridview Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, search, datagridview

I have been stuck in creating search for Datagridview in Vb.net.

I have one `DataGridView` that is bound to binding source. It contains data such as:

```
123456,
213926,
285643,
395687,
```

I have searched but everywhere but I only found a filter method for binding source or a find method.
The filter method removes remaining rows & find method finds an exact string.

I found a method to find text in `DataGridView` but that search found the string anywhere in `DataGridView` column like if user type 2 then it will first select the row having 2 such as 123456.

I want to create search that should find letter in sequence from start & so on. 
If the user presses 2 then search should go for cell starting with 2 such as 213926.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782944/search-through-columns-in-a-datagridview-using-textbox-vb-net

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Dear Frank! this solution is also finding the whole string. I mentioned earlier that I want to search sequentially with partial string from start.

Comment: This part of the code handles that: `If InStr(1, dgvString, strFind, vbTextCompare) <> 0`. You'll want to change that to `If InStr(1, dgvString, strFind, vbTextCompare) = 1`, which indicates the string was found starting at the first character.

Comment: I just noticed that the answer I copied from has been deleted, probably for good reasons. How about you first show us what you've tried, so we can work from that?

Comment: Here is my Code. From your suggested Link
`Dim toSearch As String = TextBox1.Text.ToString
Dim colNum As Integer = 13
Dim res = Dset.Tables("si_ReceiptMaster").AsEnumerable.Where(Function(x) x.Item(colNum).ToString() = toSearch).ToArray
            For Each item In res
                Dim curRow As Integer = Dset.Tables("si_ReceiptMaster").Rows.IndexOf(item)
                dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows(curRow).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
            Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matter solved Frank. Thankyou So Much.
Here is my complete code for others too.

```
Dim Found As Boolean = False
Dim StringToSearch As String = ""
Dim ValueToSearchFor As String = Me.TextBox1.Text.Trim.ToLower
Dim CurrentRowIndex As Integer = 0
Try
  If dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows.Count = 0 Then
         CurrentRowIndex = 0
  Else
         CurrentRowIndex = dgvDishonourReceipts.CurrentRow.Index + 1
  End If
  If CurrentRowIndex > dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows.Count Then
         CurrentRowIndex = dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows.Count - 1
  End If
  If dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows.Count > 0 Then
       For Each gRow As DataGridViewRow In dgvDishonourReceipts.Rows
          StringToSearch = gRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString.Trim.ToLower
          If InStr(1, StringToSearch, LCase(Trim(TextBox1.Text)), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            Dim myCurrentCell As DataGridViewCell = gRow.Cells(4)
            Dim myCurrentPosition As DataGridViewCell = gRow.Cells(0)
            dgvDishonourReceipts.CurrentCell = myCurrentCell
            CurrentRowIndex = dgvDishonourReceipts.CurrentRow.Index
            Found = True
          End If
          If Found Then Exit For
        Next
  End If
Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```